# Udating statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem with my database, which has many tables but i am focused on the main named `TblLivroPorta(t1)` and the 2nd one named `Tblp_h(t2)`.

so t1 comunicate with the application while t2 stores everything that happens with `t1`, I can say that `t2` is the `t1's` backup.

I want to find the data I am looking for in `t2` and copy them to `t1` so they can be accessed by the application.

The statement below gives me all data I want to copy back

```
select NOrdem, Num_Oficio from tblp_h  where Num_Oficio != '3469/3ª V/TAPS/2012' 
    and Data_Saida between '2012-01-01' and '2012-11-30' 
    union select NOrdem, Num_Oficio from TbLivroPorta 
    where Num_Oficio = null and Data_Saida between '2012-01-01' and '2012-11-30'
```

so my difficult is to copy them back to `t1`.

I hope I have been clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `INSERT INTO SELECT` to copy the values from one table to another

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

You need to ensure that your `SELECT` statement returns the columns that will be inserted into the target table